# I am facing an error when I try to run my angular frontend on vs code due to a prime ng check box error

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript

Error: src/app/auth/login/login.component.html:20:58 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'binary' since it isn't a known property of 'p-checkbox'.

1. If 'p-checkbox' is an Angular component and it has 'binary' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-checkbox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

20                             <p-checkbox id="rememberme1" [binary]="true" styleClass="mr-2">

I tried importing the check box module in my auth.module.ts file and using npm install primeng to solve the error but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to add the CheckboxModule to your *.module.ts

looks something like this

```
import { CheckboxModule } from 'primeng/checkbox';
...
@NgModule({imports: [CheckboxModule,...
```